# jQuery DataTables cell styling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, datatables

I'm using jQuery DataTables, and I am able to look at the row data and colorize the row.

Here is the code that creates the datatable:

```
 var $dataTable = $('#example1').DataTable({
   "data": data,
   "dataType": "json",
   "iDisplayLength": 25,
   "order": [[6, "desc"]],
   "scrollY": 550,
   "scrollX": true,
   "bDestroy": true,
   "stateSave": true,
   // here is the part that styles the row
   "fnRowCallback": function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull)
   {
     if (aData[12] == "Y"){$('td', nRow).css('background-color', '#EE6363');}
     if (aData[9] == "Y"){$('td', nRow).css('font-weight', 'bold');}
   }
 });
```

So if you'll notice in the code above, the 1st `if` statement checks if the row data of the 12th column, which is called REJECTED, is "Y".  If so, make the entire row red.

The 2nd `if` statement checks if the row data of the 9th column, which is called URGENT, is "Y".  If so, make the text for that entire row bold.

What I would like to do is make the cell for that column red instead of the whole row, primarily for the 1st row.

How can I alter my code above to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that will color the target cell:

```
 if (aData[12] == "Y"){$('td', nRow).eq(1).css('background-color', '#BF5FFF');}
```

By adding eq(1), I can target and color the 2nd cell in the datatable.  This is how I got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it....

But I would try something like this :

```
if (aData[12] == "Y"){$('td', nRow)[12].css('background-color', '#EE6363');}
```

Or this tricky thing:

```
if (aData[12] == "Y"){$('td', nRow).parent().children()[12].css('background-color', '#EE6363');}
```

If zero-based:

```
if (aData[12] == "Y"){$('td', nRow)[11].css('background-color', '#EE6363');}
```

Or:

```
if (aData[12] == "Y"){$('td', nRow).parent().children()[11].css('background-color', '#EE6363');}
```